# WPF accessing a resource from anywhere in the assembly using relative path

Tags: c#, wpf, relative-path

In my application I am creating a ton of custom controls that I'm then using in different windows. The structure of my project looks something like this:

- Controls (folder)

  - MemberList (class)
- Resources  (folder)
- Windows (folder)

  - Window1.xaml
  - Window2.xaml
  - Helper windows (folder)

    - Window3.xaml

I am creating classes (controls) that I store in the Controls folder. If I want to use an image in the control, I access it like so:

```
new Uri("../Resources/my_image.png", UriKind.Relative)
```

Sometimes though, I want to use the same control in multiple windows and sometimes these windows are stored in different folders. If I use the control in say Window3 that is stored in another folder, the image is not displayed.

If I change the Uri to this: (adding another "go back" command in the path)

```
new Uri("../../Resources/my_image.png", UriKind.Relative)
```

the image is being displayed in the Window3, but it is not displayed in the Window1 or Window2.

Is there a way to create paths that are relative to the main executable and not relative to the window that is displaying the control?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention one important part. Because of the fact that while starting this application I was just learning how to use WPF, I messed one thing. My resources folder is not in the folder that contains the main executable.

My file structure looks like this:

- bin

  - Debug

    - MyApplication.exe
- Resources

I was trying to use the path that everyone suggested:

```
 new Uri("pack://application:,,,/../../my_image.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
```

but I get the exception:

> Cannot locate resource 'my_image.png'.

I could try to relocate the Resources folder, but it would mess up all other paths. Is there any way to go "back" in folder structure in the "pack" uri? If not, what would be the best way to relocate a folder so all paths do not get messed up?

Comment: Use a "pack" url....and refer to the component that contains the actual resource e.g.: pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyOrApplicationName;component/Resources/my_image.png

Comment: Just in case, do not specify `UriKind.Relative` on a Pack URI. None of the three answers is actually giving you an appropriate example.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you, it is an important comment. Please look at the edited part of my question to find some additional info.

Comment: You haven't read the online documentation linked in the answers. `pack://application:,,,/../../my_image.png` is an invalid Pack URI. Besides that, better do not specify an UriKind at all.

Comment: @MarcinBator Have you figured out in the end how to go "back" in folder structure? I'm having the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66783557/5616592

Comment: @YurenHuang I definitely did figure out how to do it, but unfortunately I have no idea what was the solution (question is 4 years old). There is a good chance that one of the answers for this question helped me solve the issue. Sorry for not beying much of a help and good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a "pack" uri...so you would use:

```
pack://application:,,,/Resources/my_image.png
```

so like this:

```
new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/my_image.png");
```

to refer to your "image" from ANY of your Windows/Controls.

If you will have other "projects"/"assemblies"...which you want to be able to refer to the resource then use:

```
pack://application:,,,/AssemblyNameContainingResource;component/Resources/my_image.png
```

And when you are adding your images in your `Resource` folder....make sure you use `Resource` as the `Build Action`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, please look at the edited part of my question to find some additional info.

Comment: I accepted this post as an answer because it provided the most information.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Pack Uri Scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)

> Resource File Pack URIs - Local Assembly
>
> The pack URI for a resource file that is compiled into the local
>   assembly uses the following authority and path:
>
> ```
> Authority: application:///.
>
> Path: The name of the resource file, including its path relative to the root of the local assembly project folder.
> ```
>
> The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that
>   is located in the root of the local assembly's project folder:
>
> pack://application:,,,/ResourceFile.xaml
>
> The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that
>   is located in a subfolder of the local assembly's project folder:
>
> pack://application:,,,/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml

Comment: Thank you for your response, please look at the edited part of my question to find some additional info.

Comment: It should be `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/my_image.png");` if Image stays in Resources folder of your project.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** Use pack URI notation.

**Example:**

Your URI would look similar to: `pack://application:,,,/Resources/my_image.png` regardless of where in the XAML you use it.

**Documentation:**

[MSDN - Pack URIs in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your response, please look at the edited part of my question to find some additional info.

Answer (score 0):

In a submodule such as `SubModuleA`, in the viewmodel of SubModuelA, when you want to access the resource file of SubModuelA instead of the started project.

For example, the resource file's directory is `StartApp/SubModuelA/Resource/Data/JsonData.json`, In viewmodel of SubModuelA it's path should be

```
string jsonFile="../../../SubModuleA/Resource/Data/JsonData.json"
```

I validated this and wrote data into the jsonFile.