# How to access an image that doesn't belong to any project/assembly with relative path

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm making a mod for Age of Empires 2 DE and my goal is to access an old texture file from the new UI's directory. The file structure is as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\AoE2DE
```

is the game folder that contains the exe.

```
AoE2DE/resources/_common/wpfg
```

is where `app.xaml` and ResourceDictionary sources reside.

Now I'm trying to access this image (from a .xaml file under `wpfg`):

```
AoE2DE/widgetui/textures/backgrounds/wide_default_background.dds
```

I tried the following, neither worked. The background didn't load.

```
<Image Source="/../../../widgetui/textures/backgrounds/wide_default_background.dds" />
<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,../../../widgetui/textures/backgrounds/wide_default_background.dds" />
```

I also tried to create a `SystemResourcesOldTextures.xaml` file under `widgetui` so that I could simply write

```
<Image Source="textures/backgrounds/wide_default_background.dds" />
```

and include this file in `app.xaml` by adding this line to `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,../../../widgetui/SystemResourcesOldTextures.xaml" />
```

Didn't work either.

Putting the absolute path in the Source works but it's not practical as everyone's game path could be different. Copying the resource into `wpfg` is also not ideal as mod size would increase by a lot.

NOTE:

- Since this is a game I don't have access to the project file, nor any C# code. I can't build/complie. I can only edit the XAML files and restart the game to verify.
- I have seen similar questions asked but no answer could yet address my issue. The image I want to access has no project/assembly associated.

Comment: Not sure if you could directly load a DDS file at all. See e.g. this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23618171/1136211

Comment: @Clemens I could. I said that I succeeded by using absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this post [Not able to reference Image source with relative path in xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835477/not-able-to-reference-image-source-with-relative-path-in-xaml)

```
<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/../../../widgetui/textures/backgrounds/wide_default_background.dds" />
```

Comment: I saw this post earlier. The 3 answers don't solve my issue. They either require Visual Studio settings, or assume the resource file is associated with some assembly.